Creating PDF annotations with Python that do not loose their attributes when opened with Adobe Reader
I am automatically adding a lot of annotations to a PDF with Python and the PyMuPDF (fitz) library. These annotations have different attributes like border colors. When opening the annotated PDF with Adobe Reader and moving the annotations, they loose their color attributes which is a known problem since every Adobe Reader handles annotations in a different way:
https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes-common-issues-and-their-solutions.html
I also tried other libraries like PyPDF but they are missing other featues like rotation of the annotations.
Is there a known fix to this or workaround? Like running a javascript to update all annotation attributes and change them to a Adobe compatible format?
Thanks for the help, I really did a lot of research but couldnt find anything fitting
PyMuPDF
PyPDF
PDFAnnot
Expected behavior:
PDF Annotations keep their attributes when being moved with Adobe reader
